# How to change swagger-ui endpoint that generates configuration (/v3/api-docs/swagger-config)

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc

I have a service that creates a swagger-ui endpoint. I want this endpoint to be hosted on a path different than default (due to Kubernetes ingress rules). This is easily achieved on springdoc swagger by using

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/myPath/swagger-ui/index.html
```

However it is trying to access configuration from a default url

```
/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
```

Unfortunately I also need this url to be on specific path. I know there is a setting to specify a path to look for swagger-config, namely:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl=/myPath/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
```

However this isn't what I'm looking for. This setting lets you specify a different source of configuration and then you need to create a resource on specified path or the resource will not be found. If I understand correctly, the default path /v3/api-docs/swagger-config is some kind of endpoint that is automatically creates/generates the resource without requiring user to create it.

What I am looking for is a way to have access to this automatically generated config on a different path. Something that would say "Generate and return me your default configuration if I access /myPath/v3/api-docs/swagger-config instead of /v3/api-docs/swagger-config". Preferably by entry in application.properties or overriding some behavior in application code

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 5):

try `springdoc.api-docs.path=/myPath/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`

https://springdoc.org/properties.html#properties

Answer (score 1):

I suppose I had a similar problem in the past and it was also related to Kubernetes and a proxy (API Gateway), which is in front of my application. I needed to have url like this `https://host/api-gw/my-app/swagger-ui.html` and then redirection to `https://host/api-gw/my-app/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/api-gw/my-app/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`. The redirection didn't work properly for me, because the `/api-gw/` part was missing in `configUrl` parameter. The solution to my problem was adding ForwardedHeaderFilter (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/ForwardedHeaderFilter.html) bean to the configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class ForwardedHeaderFilterConfig {

  @Bean
  ForwardedHeaderFilter forwardedHeaderFilter() {
    return new ForwardedHeaderFilter();
  }
}
```

After that, redirection worked fine and the `configUrl` parameter was set to `api-gw/my-app/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`.